# add_filter postbox_classes multiple post types

Tags: plugin-development, filters

I am trying to add classes to my metabox. How could I apply this to both post and pages?  $posts variable? Do I need to add filter twice, once for each post type?

```
    $id = 'my-metabox-api';
    $posts = array('post', 'page');
    add_meta_box($id, 'My Video Player', 'add_metabox_api', $posts, 'normal', 'low'); 

    add_filter( "postbox_classes_{$posts}_{$id}", 'my_custom_mb' );

function my_custom_mb( $classes ) {
    array_push( $classes, 'closed' );
    return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to add filter twice, once for each post type?

**Yes!** you can't insert an array into a string, if you could it wouldn't result in a matching filter name anyway. The filters for posts and pages are different filters. You need to add them separately.

e.g. `postbox_classes_post_my-metabox-api` versus `postbox_classes_page_my-metabox-api`

If I had to guess, your current code results in this filter name: `postbox_classes_array_my-metabox-api`